# my remote branches list is empty in git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I can commit to my local repository without a problem but when trying to pull or push I get the following issue -- my remote repository list is empty..  I think my password is corrupt but I don't know how to create a new password, assuming that's the problem..  Any ideas?
Thanks,

**Screen shot from SourceTree**

[image]

**Command prompt attempt**

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the result of: git remote -v please?

Comment: have added this to my question update

Comment: I ask the stupid question now so we get rid of it: Is the "gif" at the end intended? Or is it "git"?